# WPF. Визуальный редактор не отображает ресурс

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

## Описание проблемы

Решил автоматизировать добавление векторной графики из SVG файлов.
Создал свой **`UserControl`**, добавил **`DependencyProperty Source`** типа **`Uri`** и в **`PropertyChangedCallback`** достаю текст SVG файла загруженного в сборку как **Resource**
*`(Свойства > Действия при сборке > Resource)`* из полученного пути:

```
string ReadResourceText(Uri Resource)
{
    var StreamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(Resource);
    var StreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(StreamInfo.Stream);
    return StreamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
//string ResourceText = ReadResourceText((Uri)e.NewValue);
```

Дальше парсил этот текст и на его основе создавал "реальные" элементы в своём контроле и задавал им свойства.
Добавил свой контрол *(называется **`VectorImage`**)* в окно:
`<local:VectorImage Source="android.svg"/>`

При компиляции программы всё работает, но в визуальном дизайнере не результат не отображается и на присвоении свойства `Source="android.svg"` выдаёт ошибку `Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта`. В чём может быть проблема?

## Код

`VectorImage.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class VectorImage : UserControl
{
    public VectorImage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty SourceProperty;

    static VectorImage()
    {
        SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(Uri), typeof(VectorImage),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSourceChanged)));
    }

    public Uri Source
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }

    static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Извлечение текста из указанного ресурса
        string ReadResourceText(Uri Resource)
        {
            var StreamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(Resource);
            var StreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(StreamInfo.Stream);
            return StreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // Получение расширения файла ресурса
        string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension((e.NewValue as Uri).OriginalString).Substring(1);
        // (sender as VectorImage).viewbox - создан в xaml (больше ничего)
        // Проверка расширения
        switch (Extension)
        {
            case "svg":
                (sender as VectorImage).viewbox.Child = Converter.FromSVG(ReadResourceText((Uri)e.NewValue));
                return;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Расширение \"" + Extension + "\" не поддерживается.");
        }
    }

    static class Converter
    {
        public static Grid FromSVG(string ResourceText)
        {
            // Тут много кода
            // Работа с текстом и создание элементов
        }
    }
}
```

## Скриншоты

[image: В редакторе]

[image: При запуске]